# Fibonacci numbers and perfect squares

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, square-numbers, golden-ratio

Can this be simplified any further?:

$\phi^{2n}$ + $\psi^{2n}$$-2(-1)^n$ $\pm4$

Where $\phi = (1+\sqrt5)/2  $

Where $\psi = (1-\sqrt5)/2 $

When n=even number, use +4

Whenn n=odd number, use -4

If anyone could show me how to simplify this further it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please type the formula out; the handwritten formula is not entirely clear.  Is there meant to be a difference between $\phi$ and $\varphi$?

Comment: Sorry my coding is very rough

Comment: A good general approach:  Let $a_n$ denote the left hand, $b_n$ the right.  Easy to confirm that $a_n=b_n$ for small $n$ (I assume, I didn't check).  Now show that the two sides satisfy the same recursion.

Comment: But...did you mean to write $(n^2-(n^2-1))^2$?  That's just $1$.

Comment: Changed that part sorry

Comment: And what do you mean for the same recursion. Using induction?

Comment: Your coding wasn't that rough. You had a lot more dollar signs than you needed, but other than that it was fine.

Comment: For example:  with $c_n=\phi^n+\psi^n$ show that $c_n$ satisfies the Fibonacci recursion, $c_n=c_{n-1}+c_{n-2}$.

Comment: So that specific example or the in the method in which that example is proven?

Comment: Not sure I follow.  Start with the right hand, because it is simpler.  What is the relation between $b_n$ and $b_{n-1}$? Once you have that, show that the $a_n$ satisfies the same relation.

Comment: so is $b_{n-1}$ equal to ($k^2$−$(k−1)^2$)^2, but instead, k=n-1 is substituted?

Comment: If we take $n=0$ the left hand is $1+1-2+4=4$ yes?  But the right hand is $(0^2-(0^2-1))^2=1$ so I think there is still some confusion.

Comment: Are you sure that this is a "theorem"? The left-hand side grows like $2^n$ at least, while the right-hand side grows at most like $4n^2$...

Comment: Hmmm...Yes you are correct the statement is incorrect. I must have stuffed up the calculations. The question is reworded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dealing with Lucas numbers, defined by $L_0=2$, $L_1=1$, $L_n=L_{n-1}+L_{n-2}$.  We have $L_n=\varphi^n+\psi^n$.

Observe that $L_n^2=\varphi^{2n}+2\varphi^n\psi^n+\psi^{2n}=L_{2n}+2(-1)^n$.